# Do I need a unit-testing framework if I'm already using Cypress in a Vue.js app?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, cypress, end-to-end

When scaffolding a new project with the Vue.js CLI, it offers a choice of both unit-testing and E2E-testing frameworks.

Unit-testing functionality is perfectly adequate in Cypress. My question, then: is there an advantage to using a distinct unit-testing framework if I'm already using Cypress?

Comment: This doesn't cover Vue specifically, but feels very relevant. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/unit-vs-integration-vs-e2e-tests and with Cypress starting to do unit/component level testing too the use-case for jest tests is definitely shrinking in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a third-party adapter made by a Cypress contributor here called [`cypress-vue-unit-test`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-vue-unit-test)(along with [unit-test adapters for other popular frameworks](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-vue-unit-test#test-adapters-for-other-frameworks)).

You should check that out and see if it meets your needs over, say,  [Jest](https://jestjs.io/)

From [this tutorial](https://alexjover.com/blog/write-the-first-vue-js-component-unit-test-in-jest/) about unit testing `vuejs`, some `Jest` advantages over `Cypress` are:

- Built in code coverage
- Snapshot testing
- Module mocking utilities

Also see repo for [vue-test-utils](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I see that Cypress has started working on snapshot testing, but it's still early days. And I see the Cypress devs' point about the dubious usefulness of code coverage, but I do still like the metric as a broad heuristic. I think I will keep Jest around :) Thanks!